# What happened to the Specialized Stumpjumper HT?

Tags: mountain-bike, specialized-bikes

I have always been a fan of Specialized, especially the Stumpjumper hardtail. I was browsing the Specialized website when I noticed that they no longer have the Stumpjumper Hardtail listed, only the Stumpjumper FSR. I did see that they now have a hardtail version of the Epic.

Did they just change the name from Stumpjumper to Epic? I really liked the name 'Stumpjumper'. What happened?

Comment: "marketing" likes to change things, retiring names and possibly bringing the name back a decade later to "evoke nostalgia" or some other advertising lies.  The name means little, its the bike that matters.

Comment: Bike companies are always changing around models and names to meet market demands.  I don't know if the Epic is functionally similar to the Stumpjumper, but I've rarely seen a company stop production on a line that's selling.  If they stopped making it, it must not have been selling as well as something they wanted to bring in.

Answer (score 4):

Ultimately Specialized has probably decided that the sales volume is not worth it. A new Epic HT will almost certainly have better trail and downhill capability as a Stumpy of even a few years ago, be lighter and have much better climbing.  Its not that they would not sell any HT Stumpy's if they had them- its more they can move a vast majority potential HT Stumpy buyers to a HT Epic or a soft tail Stumpy. The lost sales not having it in the range would be very minimal.

Keeping hold of a HT Trail (the stumpy) - for which there is no longer big demand that cannot be met buy a salesman diverting to another model, does not make sense as the range of bikes is probably too large already, with too much overlap.

The Stumpy goes back to early 1990s (or is it earlier) - and has undergone numerous transitions. Its just a name - the bikes you like are nothing like the ones in the shop today.

Comment: There is also a case to be made for the fact that the name "Stumpjumper" is their name for a top end trail bike.  The Epic is a XC race bike.  Once a XC WC was won on a full suspension rig (an Epic) it was clear where the market was headed.  The move is possibly a statement that decent trail bikes should now be full suspension, just as some years ago a move was made that a decent mountain bike should have disc brakes.  In a few years, it's likely that XC hardtails will start to disappear too.

Comment: @DeletedUser You may not be wrong, but I for one hope that hardtails don't disappear.  A decent rear suspension adds several hundred dollars to the base price of the bike - one of the advantages of HT bikes is their relative affordability and simplicity.

If XC riding becomes so technical that full suspension is a requirement, is it really XC riding anymore?  Personally, I am distinctly NOT looking for drops, jumps, or anything that would call for RS, and I thought that was the difference between XC and trail.

Comment: @JoshDoebbert Feel free to continue in chat....https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74453/what-happened-to-the-specialized-stumpjumper-ht-discussion

Answer (score 0):

I own an older model Specialized Epic full suspension, a StumpJumper Hardtail, and a StumpJumper full suspension.  I think the new Epic Hardtail has essentially replaced the Stumpy HT (which is a race machine like the Epic).  I have photos of these bikes and others I own/ride at https://www.flickr.com/photos/rbinv/albums/72157647973102794